# Stream USB mic input to 3.5mm audio jack output

Tags: usb, audio

I am trying to stream a USB mic input to the raspberry pi's built in 3.5mm audio jack output. I am not sure how to do this. I essentially want to use the Pi as a DAC. How could I do this?

Comment: These may be helpful: https://computers.tutsplus.com/articles/using-a-usb-audio-device-with-a-raspberry-pi--mac-55876 , https://makersportal.com/blog/2018/8/23/recording-audio-on-the-raspberry-pi-with-python-and-a-usb-microphone , http://wiki.sunfounder.cc/index.php?title=To_use_USB_mini_microphone_on_Raspbian